# Getting programmatic access to MacOS system performance statistics

Tags: performance, macos

When you run [`top`](https://web.archive.org/web/20140604074226/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/top.1.html) or [Activity Monitor](https://web.archive.org/web/20120505040859/http://macdevcenter.com/lpt/a/6248) on Mac OS X, you see a variety of performance data for the whole system - current and historic CPU usage, physical memory and swap space usage, disk activity, and so on.  On Linux and some other Unix-like systems, you can access this data in your own programs by using kernel system calls or by looking in the `/proc` and/or `/sys` pseudo-filesystems.

Unfortunately, MacOS lacks both `/proc` and `/sys`, and a few web searches don't reveal many syscalls that provide whole-computer performance data.  Hence this question:

How might you access MacOS system performance data from your C program?

Answer (score 4):

The functions and structures to get this information are described in `/usr/include/libproc.h` and `/usr/include/sys/proc.h`. `libproc.h` has this warning though

```
/*
 * This header file contains private interfaces to obtain process information.  
 * These interfaces are subject to change in future releases.
 */
```

The functions are found in libSystem. They look pretty straightforward to use.